# what is the function of 은 in the sentence below?

Tags: grammar

I came across this sentence

> 철수 씨만큼**은** 술을 못 마셔요.

but I don't know how 은 works in this sentence

Answer (score 0):

Literal tranlation: Can't drink as much as 철수

은/는 is used to make a comparasion. The one saying this sentence states that they  can't drink as much as 철수.

I really recommend you to watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sgwRiTm7UwI&pp=ugMICgJrbxABGAE%3D) video. It explains the Subject Marking Particles really well.

Answer (score 0):

The 은 there is used to mark contrast (and sometime the syllable will be emphasized when spoken).  It means something like "As much as Chulsoo? No [I] can't drink that much."

An example scenario where this sentence fits could be: people are talking who could drink the most amount of soju without getting blackout drunk, and there's another guy 철수, who is also known to drink a lot, so people ask who are the "better" drinker, and you answer:

> (Yeah I am a fair drinker, but) I can't drink as much as Chulsoo.

So the contrast is that you'd say Yes if someone asks "Can you drink a lot?" but if the question becomes "As much as Culsoo?" then the answer is No.  Other examples are:

> 한라산은 높지만 백두산만큼**은** 높지 않다. (or)

> 한라산은 높지만 백두산만큼 높지**는** 않다.